# How to prevent xdotool from locking the current window after a script?

Tags: xorg, troubleshooting

I have a simple BASH script with `xdotool`, that reads some data from a CSV, and enters it into a form in some other software:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5

while read -r line
do
    a="$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')"
    xdotool type $a
    xdotool key "$Tab"
done < ./data.csv

aplay Beep.wav
```

The script works as intended, but after the beep tone, the screen becomes locked:

- The mouse moves, but no windows can see it (e.g. tool tips do not appear) and it cannot click on anything, even the current window.
- The keyboard words, but only within the current window.
- The window is locked in this manner for about 5 minutes, then suddenly is not locked anymore.

CTRL+ALT+F1 allows me to change consoles, but `killall -9 xfce4-terminal` and `killall -9 xdotool` did not stop the lock.

How can I prevent `xdotool` from locking the current window after running it in a script?

Answer (score 0):

It beeps because it's waiting for you to click on the window you want it to interact with.  Didn't you notice the cursor change to a '+' symbol?

Read the man page again.  You need to provide a window id (--window *id*)

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this rather old question looking for an answer myself, because I have/had a similar problem. I use xdotool to auto-type login information on websites (in firefox).

I bound a key combination to a script with xbindkeys. The script identifies the windowname (also with xdotool), looks for an associated entry in an encrypted file, loads the appropriate login info and types it.

I'm not going to explain the intricacies of my script, the user interaction with it and the way it enters info into input fiels. However, I solved the issue by **adding a short sleep just before the actual typing**.

```
sleep 0.4
xdotool type ...
```

I admit this is a hackish solution, but it seems to work. I hope this solution can be of some help to anyone else looking to overcome this very frustrating bug(?), or maybe urges someone else to write a better answer.